# Run LWC open source app on HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: lightning-web-components

Hi I am playing with LWC open source and want to host it on HTTPS, default it is on HTTP.
I ran the below to run app on http;

> 1. npx create-lwc-app my-app
> 2. cd my-app
> 3. npm run watch

App runs on http://localhost:3001/

I tried to modify the "script/express-dev.js" like below but it donot work.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

const customServer = require(path.resolve('./src/server/'));

const app = express();

customServer(app);

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('./src/server/key.pem', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./src/server/cert.pem', 'utf8')
}, app).listen(3005, () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('Yay, local server started');
});
```

Also tried to make changes in lwc-services.config but not sure if they are correct.

```
module.exports = {
resources: [{ from: 'src/client/resources', to: 'dist/resources' }],
sourceDir: './src/client',
moduleDir: './src/client/modules',
server: {
    port: 3006,
    customConfig: './src/server/server.js'
},
devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    proxy: { '/': 'http://localhost:3001' },
    https: true
}
};
```

Need suggestion/solution.

Comment: have you tried [https-localhost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-localhost) ?

Comment: thanks but i am looking in how to it using express.js